# Need help with a database design for Top 10

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am trying to come up with a database design to hold the "Top 10" results for some calculations that are being done. Basically, when all is said in done, there will be 3 "Top 10" categories, which I am fine with all being separate tables, however I need to be able to go back and later pull historical data about what was in the Top 10 at certain times, hence the need for a database, although a flat-file would work, this has the potential to hold years worth of data.

Now, it's been awhile since I have done anything serious with a database, other than something that had a couple of simple tables, so I am having some issues thinking through this design. If someone could help me with the design of it, I know enough MySQL to get the rest done.

So, in essence, I need to store: A group of 10 names, a % of the total points each name had, the rank they held in the Top 10 and a time associated with that Top 10 (So I can later query for that time)

I would think I need a table for for the Top 10 with 11 columns, one for the ID and 10 for the Foreign Key of the 'Names' table, that holds every name ever used with a PK, Name, %, and Rank. This seems clunky to me, anyone else have a suggestion?

**edit**:The 'Top 10' is associated with a specific set of data for 5-minute intervals, and each interval is completely independent from the previous or future intervals.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend your solution, because then if you want to ask the database "How often has Joe been in the top 10," you have to write 10 queries of the form

```
SELECT Date FROM Top10 WHERE FirstPlace = 'joe'
SELECT Date FROM Top10 WHERE SecondPlace = 'joe'
...
```

Instead, how about a Rankings table, with fields:

```
id
Date
Person
Rank
```

Then if you want the Top 10 list for a certain date, the query is

```
SELECT * FROM Rankings WHERE Date = ...
```

and if you want to know someone's historical ranking, the query is

```
SELECT * FROM Rankings WHERE Person = ...
```

and if you want to know all the historical leaders, the query is

```
SELECT * FROM Rankings WHERE Rank = 1
```

The downside to this is that you might accidentally make two different people 8th place, and your database would allow the anomaly. But I have good news for you -- people might actually tie for 8th place, so you might actually want that to be possible!

Comment: I'm not sure that would work. The names actually come from syslog data that I query, each one with it's own ranking according to whatever the Top 10 is looking for. The data is worked on in 5 minute chunks, and each 5 minute chunk is treated independently. So for each and every 5 minute chunk, there is a Top 10, which are totally independent of the previous groups of 5 minutes.

It isn't a running average or running total, each 5 minute period is indepdendent. But yes, names may show up more than once within all of the Top 10s. I should have specified that in the original question.

Comment: There aren't any running totals in my suggestion. By my design, each 5 minute chunk would cause 10 records to be inserted into the database: the 10 records would correspond to the facts "In chunk X, Bob was #1," "In chunk X, Joe was #2," "In chunk X, Jill was #3," etc. When you ran Chunk Y, you would add 10 more records. The fact that I used "date" instead of "time" shouldn't prevent you from adapting this to your situation.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread your post. So you are suggesting a single table and querying based strictly on the date/time for presenting the Top 10? You don't feel that would end up slow to search/query after every 5 minute interval is collected for a long period of time?

Comment: That's maybe a valid concern, but I really think this is the right way to do it. Unless you can guarantee that you will never ever need to access your data in certain ways ("I'll never want to know how many times Joe was on the list!" or "I'll never ever be curious how many times there was a tie for first place!"), I don't see any way to store less data but still capture all the information.

Comment: @z0dSki -- a properly indexed table will have more or less constant access time no matter how many rows are in the table. Every now and then you will get a slower insert as it needs split pages in the index etc. but I would be surprised if anyone noticed.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your "Top 10" is a snapshot data in certain time. And your business logic is that "every 5 minutes" so that the time is the parent entity for table design

```
top_10_history
    th_id - the primary key
    th_time - the time point when taking the snapshot data of "Top 10"
top_10_detail
    td_th_id - the FK to top_10_history
    td_name_id - the FK to name
    td_percentage - the "%"
    td_rank - the rank
```

1. If the sequence of "Top 10" could be calculated from columns in "top_10_detail", you don't need a column to keep the sequence of it. Otherwise, you need a column to persist the sequence for it.
2. If you need more complicated query such as "The top 10 at 12:00 AM in last 30 days", using individual columns for "day", "hour", and "minute" would be a better idea for performance(with suitable indexes).